# How to refresh Model on the client side with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC app that is performing some potentially long running searches and I'd like to be able to stream back results as I get them in, rather than wait for the entire query to complete and returning all hits at once.

Here is what I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); 
        setTimeout(refreshModel(), 5000);

        function refreshModel() {

            model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //How do I get an updated model?
            populateResults(model.SearchResults);
            if (model.LoadingItems)
                setTimeout(refreshModel(), 10000);
        }
        /* snip */
   </script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work like you want. I don't think that you can only partially load the model, then just out of nowhere have more data on the model. ASP.NET is going to load the full model no matter what. You may have to have some asynchronous JS function that every 5000 ms or whatever reaches out to the server to grab more data. You will then need to apply the results to the page.

Comment: @LukeBecker I don't really care how I get it. A js function to pull the data is fine.

Comment: You could use a SignalR connection to push the data back to the client as it is available.

Comment: Create a handler (or webapi method) that will return the updated model, in refreshModel do an AJAX call to load the refreshed model, when that's done call populateResults with the value returned from your handler.